# Cheap simple way to make an adjustable 1-10 MHz square or sine wave oscillator

Tags: filter, oscillator, test

For a test of a filter and video transmitter gear, I need a variable frequency (potentiometer adjusted) sine or square wave oscillator, adjustable from about 1 to 10 MHz. Output about 1Vp-p okay, but I could reduce a higher output. I don't have many parts at the moment; so I need the cheapest way to do this. I have a lot of NOR gates lying around and I'm thinking of a ring oscillator but when I try to make them adjustable they become unstable.

Answer (score 4):

How about an oscillator around a Schmitt-Trigger inverter? Capacitor on input, resistor from output to capacitor, done.

[image: relaxation oscillator]

Comment: has to be a schmitt-trigger; without the hysteresis it will just settle at a voltage somewhere near the middle of the rails.

Comment: Is there any drawback to using an op-amp based schmitt trigger over one of the 74HC14s?

Comment: @Ranieri - not really. I posted this because it's the absolutely minimum component count solution. It has fixed trigger levels, however, in the opamp version you can set the trigger levels yourself.

Comment: Getting an op amp circuit to oscillate at 1 MHz to 10 MHz will be very difficult!

Comment: This circuit is nice, but I've used them at my college and even on a little PCB designed exactly for this most chips can only manage ~3.5 MHz. I had an old 74LS00 NAND gate lying around, and I got that to go up to 75 MHz(!)

Comment: @Leon - you're right (I forgot the frequency requirements for a moment.)